# Handling postback situation in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, testng, postback

Hello on the project that im working on has a scenario where if a user does not select options from drop_down and clicks next button a  error message is given..
Now i would like to check if the message displayed is the intended message or not...

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSend']")).click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  String message=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divMsg']")).getText();
  Assert.assertEquals("Please select the event/activity you wish to claim points for", message);
```

as we can see on click button the following message is given

> PASSED: login
>   PASSED: claimpoints
>   FAILED: withoutdropdownselection
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (507, 598). Other element would receive the click: ...
>     (Session info: chrome=60.0.3088.4)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 111 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'AKHIL-PC', ip: '192.168.1.38', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30), userDataDir=C:\Users\Akhil\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir13456_26342}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=60.0.3088.4, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
>   Session ID: 73b1cf7ec5d8ffd26f92aff6660b8f1a

Comment: If your question is answered to your liking please consider marking one of the answers as the answer: [How to mark a question as answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 1):

Add some wait for that element to be clickable before clicking your button:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSend']"))));
```